# Event Sync - Salesforce Public Calendar with SharePoint Calendar

Tags: integration, calendar, workflowoutboundmessage

The ask is to sync the event details from Salesforce Public Calendar with SharePoint Calendar. This should happen when an event is created in SF. I would like your views on the feasibility of using Outbound Messages to achieve this. The SharePoint is internal to the Enterprise and the users are authenticated via the directory.

I had also investigated on the Sunlight search which is in Pilot but seems it is to search documents across both SF & SharePoint. I could not make much headway. Any pointers would certainly help.

Comment: while this is a perfectly reasonable question, it's not something that's appropriate for this site.  Please review the [faq] for more details.

Comment: Thanks Ralph; however it is for sure something to do with Salesforce integration with SharePoint. I reviewed the FAQ and did not find anything which is objectionable related to this question. It falls with in the purview of an Administrator/Developer who had done this previously and could help me understand the steps.

Comment: You've got a point, our [faq] appears to be a little out of date, check out this [meta discussion](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/102/594).  Some tips to improve the question so it doesn't feel like you're asking us to [do your homework](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/351/594).  List out what research you've already done, and try narrowing it down to a specific question.  Would be happy to upvote this after that